# VBA storing column in another sheet

Tags: vba

I am trying to copy column values (which are created via rand() function) to another sheet for a specific number of itereations.  For example for 10 iterations, recalculate column 10 times and store the values after each instance in another sheet resulting in 10 columns. I know that I am supposed to use paste values and create a loop with an offset function, but I am not sure how to do this.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

This will copy data in column A of Sheet1 to Columns in Sheet2, starting at column A and working right:

```
Dim rowOffset As Double

rowOffset = IIf(Sheet2.Range("A1") = vbNullString, 0, Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count)

Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(, rowOffset)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Here is my actual implementation:

Comment: Sub store_sim_cf()

For i = 1 To 250

Dim rowOffset As Double

rowOffset = IIf(Sheet7.Range("A12") = vbNullString, 0, Sheet7.Range("A12").Columns.Count)

Sheet1.Range("GK15:GK372").Copy
Sheet7.Range("A12").Offset(, rowOffset + i - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Next

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Sub store_sim_cf()

For i = 1 To 250

Dim rowOffset As Double

rowOffset = IIf(Sheet7.Range("A12") = vbNullString, 0, Sheet7.Range("A12").Columns.Count)

Sheet1.Range("GK15:GK372").Copy
Sheet7.Range("A12").Offset(, rowOffset + i - 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Next

End Sub